# Generic templates not working - IBM Watson and Facebook integration

Tags: facebook, chatbot, ibm-watson, facebook-messenger-bot, watson-assistant

Currently, I am developing a DB2 database-driven IBM Watson Assistant chatbot in Facebook page, integrated with IBM Cloud Functions. I have established the connection and able to send and receive messages on Facebook.

Now, I am trying to send Generic templates referencing to [Facebook developer doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic) and implement a carousel of cards in facebook with images, titles and buttons.

**Things I tried:** According to [IBM documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant-data?topic=assistant-data-dialog-responses-json), I tried **message.attachment.payload** (specified in facebook developer doc) inside **output.facebook** in Watson JSON editor.

```
{
"output": {
"generic": [{
    "values": [{
        "text": "ok"
    }],
    "response_type": "text",
    "selection_policy": "sequential"
}],
"facebook": {
    "text": "Hi,\n\nWe have a great giveaway for you, but first we’d like for you to follow us so that you can stay updated on the latest news and trends.\n\nPlease take a moment to follow us and let me know when you've followed us by typing DONE:\n\n",
    "buttons": [{
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/ibmcommerce/",
        "type": "web_url",
        "title": "Follow IBM Commerce",
        "messenger_extensions": "false",
        "webview_height_ratio": "full"
    }],
    "template_type": "generic"
  }
 }
}
```

Also, I tried implementing the solution provided in [IBM Watson developer forum](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-connector/issues/51)

```
{
  "output": {
"facebook": {
  "message": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "text": "Hi,\n\nWe have a great giveaway for you, but first we’d like for you to follow us so that you can stay updated on the latest news and trends.\n\nPlease take a moment to follow us and let me know when you've followed us by typing DONE:\n\n",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/ibmcommerce/",
            "type": "web_url",
            "title": "Follow IBM Commerce",
            "messenger_extensions": "false",
            "webview_height_ratio": "full"
          }
        ],
        "template_type": "button"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Neither of the solutions works for me. Kindly help me in figuring out what I am missing.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. update your webhook to an April version (`2020-04-01`)
2. instead of `output.facebook` use `output.integrations.facebook`

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467583/how-to-do-generic-template-of-messenger-facebook-with-ibm-watson-assistant-dialo